# Count all rows that are within a date range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to count the number of rows in my sheet that meet 3 sets of criteria: the client name in column C matches my active row; the due date in column G; and column M is blank (indicating no previous submission was sent).

I can get this to work just fine with the following code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Broker Workflow")

Dim i As Long
Dim iVal As Long

Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim strClient As String: strClient = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value
Dim strRenDate As String: strRenDate = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value
Dim strNotSubmitted As String: strNotSubmitted = ""

Dim strCriteria As String: strCriteria = strClient & strRenDate & strNotSubmitted

iVal = 0
    
    For i = 8 To lastRow
        If ws.Range("C" & i).Value & ws.Range("G" & i).Value & ws.Range("M" & i).Value = strCriteria Then
            iVal = iVal + 1
        End If
   Next i
   
Dim strCount As String: strCount = iVal
```

My problem is that now I want to extend this to count all rows with a due date that is within a range of my active row date +/- 7 days (14 day range). So if my due date is 07/06/2020 it will count the number of rows that match my client name in C, have blank cell in M and a date of anything between 01/06/2020-14/06/2020 in G.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your data? Make sure we see what `ActiveCell` is selected in that screenshot and tell which range you want to count and what the result should be according to the shown data in the screenshot. That would help a lot. Reading [mcve] might also help to improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than needed... can get rid of the four variables above, and simply test like this:

```vb
For i = 8 To lastRow
    If ws.Range("C" & i).Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value & _
        ws.Range("M" & i).Value = "" & _
        ws.Range("G" & i).Value >= DateAdd(Cells(-7, "d", ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value) & _
        ws.Range("G" & i).Value <= DateAdd(Cells(7, "d", ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value) Then
         iVal = iVal + 1
    End If
Next i
```

[EDIT]
Sorry!
I have no idea what I wrote earlier.

I mixed up the parameters in DateAdd and used `&` instead of `and`

This works, tested:

```vb
For i = 8 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, "C").Value = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C").Value And _
            Cells(i, "M").Value = "" And _
            Cells(i, "G").Value >= DateAdd("d", -7, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value) And _
            Cells(i, "G").Value <= DateAdd("d", 7, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G").Value) Then
             iVal = iVal + 1
        End If
Next i
```

It will also work with your `ws.Range` syntax, it was just simpler for me to test it like this with `Cells`
Please note that the current line also gets counted if it has an empty M column...

Comment: This returned a compile error so tried `>= DateAdd("d",-7,Cells(ActiveCell.Row,"G").Value)` instead but it threw me a result of 17 when it should've been 2! I don't even have 17 rows of entries in my sheet yet (still in trial mode)!

Comment: Amazing thank you so much @corrado that worked a treat :)